# php file rename error using php rename function

Tags: php

```
<?php
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    { 
        $q1="insert into delinked values('".$data[0]."','".$data[1]."','".$data[2]."');"; //inserts the all the data into delinked 
        //$result1=mysqli_query($conn,$q1)or die("error");//executes query
        $a=basename($data[2]).PHP_EOL;//gets the filename
        $change="D".$a; // changes the file in (D_filename format)
        $tar="/DATA".$change;

        chdir('E:\DATA');
        rename($a,$change);
    }
?>
```

When I try to rename the file I get the following error:

> ****Warning: rename(E:/DATA/windows.rar ,E:/DATA/er.php): The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (code:
>    123) in C:\Users\yathi\Desktop\Cilicosys Project\deactivate.php on
>    line 27****

Comment: I think it should be `E:\ ` instead of `E:/` see [Microsoft naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#naming_conventions)

Comment: @WillParky93 windows supports both formats

Comment: @Yathish b yadava are you sure those volume exist?

Comment: `****Warning: rename(E:/DATA/windows.rar ,E:/DATA/er.php)` does `$a` contain a space at the end or has PHP added that themselves?

Comment: any reason to attach `PHP_EOL` at `basename($data[2]).PHP_EOL`?

Comment: you're adding an end-of-line (EOL) character to the end of the name. Filenames can't contain characters like that. Not sure what you thought this was achieving?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but your code is wide open to both SQL Injection and arbitrary code execution and should be fixed in that regards.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, you are adding a "newline" character (`PHP_EOL`) to the `$a` variable (which is then propagated to `$change`). This causes `rename` to fail because this is not an allowed character in a filename.

The basic failing can be reproduced with

```
$a = "test.tst".PHP_EOL;                  
$targ = "moved.tst".PHP_EOL;                      
rename($a, $targ);
/*
Outputs : Warning. No such file or directory
*/
```

To fix your issue, just correct the line :

```
$a=basename($data[2]); //gets the filename
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but your code is wide open to both SQL Injection and arbitrary code execution and should be fixed in that regards.

Comment: you should add this comment to the question, not to your own answer.

Comment: @noam indeed, I did click on the wrong "add a comment" link, thanks